# Save matrix column-wise in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to understand this code but I can't:
The n x n matrix is saved column wise. I distinguish between full (F), upper (U) and lower (L) matrix. 
n is the dimension of the matrix

```
int sum(int k){
int s = 0;
for (int i = 1; i<=k; i++)
    s += i;
return s;}


double getentry(int j, int k){
    j--;k--;

    assert(typ == 'F' || typ == 'U' || typ == 'L');
    assert(k<n && j<n);

    if(typ == 'F') return mat[k*n+j];
    if(typ == 'L') return (k>j)?(0.0):(mat[k*n+j-sum(k)]);  
    if(typ == 'U') return (j>k)?(0.0):( mat[k*n+j-sum(n-1)+sum(n-(k+1))]);
}
```

I specifically dont understand this lines:

```
if(typ == 'L') return (k>j)?(0.0):(mat[k*n+j-sum(k)]);  
    if(typ == 'U') return (j>k)?(0.0):( mat[k*n+j-sum(n-1)+sum(n-(k+1))]);
```

But I would appreciate it if you could explain this line as well:

```
if(typ == 'F') return mat[k*n+j];
```

Comment: *I specifically dont understand this lines:* -- Too broad.  What don't you understand?  The syntax?  The formula?  The `return` statement?  The `ternary operator`?

Comment: take a piece of paper, draw a U, L and a F matrix and enumerate the elements from 1 to N, then you can understand what that code does

Comment: I dont understand the formula (the terms between the [...])

Comment: btw already C.F.Gauss knew how to get the result of `sum(k)` in a more efficient way :P

Comment: did you understand how to get the matrix element back by typ? you have to be able to solve this problem on a paper first. Second step is the programming...

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
   if(typ == 'L') return (k>j)?(0.0):(mat[k*n+j-sum(k)]);  
        if(typ == 'U') return (j>k)?(0.0):( mat[k*n+j-sum(n-1)+sum(n-(k+1))]);
```

sign the use of the [packed storage schem](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node123.html) to store your matrix.

Also note that IMHO the overall code quality is quite low, for instance no need to compute `sum(k)` with a *for-loop*, its explicit expression is (k+1)*k/2, etc.